# Memory errors using xarray + dask - use groupby or apply_ufunc?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, pandas-groupby, dask, python-xarray

I am using xarray as the basis of my workflow for analysing fluid turbulence data, but I'm having trouble leveraging dask correctly to limit memory usage on my laptop.

I have a dataarray `n` with dimensions `('t', 'x', 'z')`, which I've split into chunks of 5 along the z dimension:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'n' (t: 801, x: 960, z: 512)>
dask.array<shape=(801, 960, 512), dtype=float32, chunksize=(801, 960, 5)>
Coordinates:
* t              (t) int64 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 ...
* x              (x) int64 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
* z              (z) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 ...
```

I want to calculate the root mean squared fluctuations of `n` over t, and return a reduced dataarray with dimensions `('x', 'z')`. I want to utilise dask to only do this operation on one chunk at a time, as I only have a couple of GB of RAM available on my laptop at any time.

I've written a generalized ufunc to calculate the root mean square of a dask array:

```
def rms_gufunc(x, axis):
    """Generalized ufunc to calculate root mean squared value of a 1d dask array."""
    squares = np.square(x)
    return np.sqrt(squares.mean(axis=-1))
```

but now I'm not sure what the best way to apply this is. As far as I can see I can either use (1) `xarray.apply_ufunc`, or (2) `groupby.reduce`.

**1. Use `apply_ufunc`**:

I can apply this function using xarray.apply_ufunc:

```
def rms(da, dim=None):
    """
    Reduces a dataarray by calculating the root mean square along dimension dim.
    """

    if dim is None:
        raise ValueError('Must supply a dimension along which to calculate rms')

    return xr.apply_ufunc(rms_gufunc, da,
                          input_core_dims=[[dim]],
                          dask='parallelized', output_dtypes=[da.dtype])

n_rms = rms(data['n'], dim='t')
n_rms.load()  # Trigger computation
```

which seems to work, but it seems more complex than necessary?

**2. Use `groupby.reduce`**:

The xarray docs seems to suggest that this is a "split-apply-combine" operation which I should be able to accomplish through something like

```
n_rms = data['n'].groupby('z').reduce(rms_gufunc, dim='t')
```

However this causes a `MemoryError`, and I'm pretty sure that's not what I want to achieve with the groupby step anyway. Am I supposed to be using `groupby_bins` to bin the data into the chunks I made along `z`?

I would like to know a) if I'm using `apply_ufunc` correctly, and b) how I would do the same thing using `groupby`.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a 3D array, I assume the following case.

The speed of water molecules over an x-z plane (960 μm x 512 μm) changes over time (801 fs).
Find the rmsf for speed at each element of the x-z plane over all time.

The numpy code would be:

```
xz_plane_rmsf = (data ** 2).mean(axis=0)
```

where data is a 3D numpy array with `shape=(801, 960, 512)`. 
The 0th, 1st, and 2nd dimensions of `data` represents time, x-coordinates, and z-coordinates. Each element of `data` represents average speed of water molecules at time t and at coordinates x and z.

The equivalent code for Dask array is:

```
# Make lazy array
xz_plane_rmsf = (data ** 2).mean(axis=0)
# Evaluate the array
xz_plane_rmsf = xz_plane_rmsf.compute()
```

where `data` is a 3D Dask array.

The only remaining problem is to convert a xarray to a Dask array.
I don't use xarray, but it looks like it is already a Dask array:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'n' (t: 801, x: 960, z: 512)>
dask.array<shape=(801, 960, 512), dtype=float32, chunksize=(801, 960, 5)>
```

Comment: I don't know if you can ask xarray to always save the t-dimension as the 0th dimension.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I think all you've done here is rewrite what my `rms_gufunc` does but to operate using dask functions instead of numpy functions. I don't understand if that has any relevant to the behaviour of `apply_ufunc` or `groupby`.

Comment: if it is a dask array instead of pandas data frames, then that already can do what you want without `apply_ufunc` or `groupby`. I don't know pandas data frames, but the dask array way looks simple enough.

Comment: My data is in the form of an xarray DataArray (similar to a Pandas DataFrame but multidimensional). My question was about how I apply the generalized ufunc I want to the xarray DataArray directly using xarray functionality. I could extract the dask array, manipulate that and then put it back in, but then my code would be less clear (and less general) then if I use xarray's functionality to do those steps for me.

Comment: The xarray DataArray is definitely the right choice of format for my data, my data is generally 4D (x,y,z,t), and originally stored as netCDF files, both of which are what xarray was designed to handle.